# Possible to git rebase to a text file, edit it and then apply from edited file?

Tags: git, git-rebase, git-history

I have to fix a HUGE history (over 300 messages). Obviously, I will have to rebase to root via `git rebase -i --root` and then reword all commits that need rewording. So you can get grasp of the scope of this work.

Is there a way to export git history to a file which I can open via sublime (or other text editor), then change commit messages in a more user-friendly manner, and after all changes have been done import changes from this file back into the Git history?

Sci-fi or reality?

Comment: `git fast-export` and `git fast-import` already exist and can be made to serve.  Otherwise a filter-branch with a map for the new messages.

Comment: @jthill Does this work on the same repo? Or `git-import` has to be executed onto a new repo?